# Need help regarding to ionic 4

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, ionic4

I need help regarding to ionic 4. I have created a footer in ionic 4 and I want to save ionic 4 footer as a template and want to include any other page where needed. Any body can help on this issue? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: `[I] want to include any other page where needed` - what is keeping you? Or should that read *want to include [**it in any page**] where needed*? (Don't comment comments asking for clarification or missing information: edit your post.)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a footer component. You can check angular documentations on how to create a component.
example :

```
ionic generate component
```

Have a look at this tutorial

> https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/